# Is there a simple way to display plain-text rendering of the query results, like you get when you run the query at the command line?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm well-versed in php and mysql and have written methods to show the results of a DB query more times than I care to recall.  I could build such a method for this, but I'm wondering (and failing to google successfully) if there's a one-line approach.

I did find that you can do `INTO 'outfile.txt'`.  But is there a way to get it straight out of the MySQL recordset/PDO resource in PHP?

`$rs->fetchAll(AS_PLAIN_TEXT)`.

That sort of thing, but not that?

Comment: If there was it would be mentioned on the [PHP Manual Pages for PDO or MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) Love to know what use you would put it to if there was, I cannot think of a sensible one.

Comment: Sometimes you just want quick and dirty, this is one of those times.  It's for some scheduled jobs I'm setting up which will run queries which should return no rows.  If they do return rows, I'd like to see them, just via an email to myself.  I prefer to send plain-text emails rather than HTML for this sort of thing, just because I always have.  ‍♂️

Comment: [fputcsv()](https://www.php.net/fputcsv) for each row is the closest equivalent. You'd only need one loop to put each row into CSV format. I don't think PDO provides a pre-made "dump result as CSV" feature.